# C++ Constness problem

Tags: c++, constants

I have a problem with whether making class members constant or not. Let me give an example.

```
#include <iostream>
class ValueClass
{
    int ival;
public:
    void set(int i) {ival = i;}
    int get() {return ival;}
};

class XXX;

class ABC
{
    ValueClass vc;  
public:
    int getval() const {return vc.get() ;}  
friend class XXX;
};

class XXX
{
    std::vector<ABC> abclist;
    void Invalidate()
    {
    // Iterates through abclist and modifies ValueClass members.
    // e.g. abclist[i].vc.set(i);
    }
};

class QWE
{
    const ABC & abc; 
public:
    QWE(const ABC & abc_): abc(abc_) { }
    const ABC & getABC() { return abc; } 
};

int main()
{
    ABC abc;
    QWE qwe(abc);

    std::cout << qwe.getABC().getval()  << "\n"; // Compiler error
}
```

My `ABC` class holds an instance of ValueClass which is responsible for having getter and setter for an `int` value. Also `QWE` class has an `ABC` member and I need to obtain this member. I am told that returning the `abc` as non-const is a very bad practice. But here comes the problem, I can not use non-const `vc` in a const `int getval()` function and I simply can not make it `const` because in another thread `XXX::Invalidate()` is called. This function changes the data in ValueClass with respect to some incoming data.
Obviously there is something wrong with my design, I can not blame the C++ language. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make get() const in ValueClass

```
  class ValueClass
  {
      int ival;
    public:
      void set(int i) {ival = i;}
      int get() const {return ival;} // make get const
  };
```

Probably should do the same for getABC

```
  const ABC & getABC() const { return abc; }
```

This means that this method does not change the object it is called on.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, the accessors should be const-qualified.  As a general rule, if something *can* be const-qualified, it *should* be const-qualified (there are a few exceptions, of course, e.g. the return type of a function that returns by value should not be const-qualified, though it *usually* doesn't matter there).

However, there is another issue with the code as written:  it is very easy to use incorrectly and accidentally lose track of your object lifetimes.  Consider if you had instead declared `qwe` in `main()` as:

```
QWE qwe(ABC());
```

The `ABC()` constructs a temporary `ABC` object and passes it to the `QWE` constrcutor.  Since the constructor parameter `abc_` is a `const ABC&`, it will bind to that temporary object.  You then bind the member reference `abc` to the temporary object via the initializer `abc(abc_)`.  The constructor then returns.

After the constructor returns, the temporary `ABC` object is destroyed and `qwe.abc` is a dangling reference:  it no longer refers to an object.

If a class is going to hang onto a reference that you pass to it, you should prefer to use a pointer for the parameter type:  this way, it is clearer that you have to concern yourself with potential lifetime issues.  In addition, reference-type class members are usually more mess than they are worth, since they make the class non-assignable (since references themselves are not assignable).

Comment: [Herb Sutter](http://stackoverflow.com/users/297582/herb-sutter) actually makes [an argument](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/006.htm) (see point 4 in his solution) for const return-by-value on non-builtin types, although he admits it's arguable.

Comment: Yes I agree. Using pointers is much easier. But here in SO there is a thought that "in Modern C++, pointers should be used only in writing libraries not in actual app code, because references takes care of everything. And one should be using RAII for this purpose." And I thought maybe I need some more practice with references.

Comment: @sad_man:  Well, while that is often said, that's not quite what is meant.  Really what is meant is "don't manage resources in application code, do it in low level library code and then build on those library facilities."  Pointers are just a tool; they are very useful for all sorts of things.  They are "bad" (quotes required) because they can make object lifetime management difficult and convoluted; however, you have the same lifetime management issues with references.

Comment: @Fred:  Yeah; I've read that article, many times, and I agree with almost everything there.  I've always found the rule for value return types to be odd and silly though:  it doesn't make any sense and there isn't any benefit to const-qualifying such return types.  Further, it's a rule that can't be applied consistently, since fundamental types have to be treated specially, and that means that it's hard to do "the right thing" in generic code (especially since certain compilers, e.g. EDG-based compilers, will warn you if you const-qualify the return type if it is a fundamental type).

Answer (score 0):

```
class ValueClass
{
    ...
    int get() const {return ival;}
};

class QWE
{
    ...
    const ABC & getABC() const { return abc; } 
};
```

Your code must be const-correct throughout or you'll run into this problem all the time.